# Bread wallet iOS app

Tags: address

I am new to bit coin and the bread wallet app, so please excuse me if this is a really obvious question.

I have read a lot of information saying that it is vital to use a new address every time I receive a payment. (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse)
The bread app presents me with a qr code with my address below it to receive money, but no apparent way to create a new address.

Am I missing something really obvious, or is it ok to use this same qr/address over and over?

Answer (score 1):

Breadwallet creates a new address every time you use the one displayed.

There is no manual way of creating a new one manually.

Comment: Thank you, I realised this not long after asking. For any other users of Bread Wallet, if you tap on the qr code, some tips come up explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use a different address every time is to help obfuscate who transactions are moving between. By itself its not all that useful unless you only use them one time and avoid any kind of pattern (or using the same IP address), but it does make tracking harder.

The questions is: Do you care? If not, just keep using the same address.

Answer (score -1):

There are no problems with using the same address over and over. I started trading more than a year ago and my 'main'-purse has still the same address.

I've taken a look for you and I didn't find the possibility to add more addresses. This application can be used for one address at a time only.

Comment: That is not correct, the wallet manages this automatically rather than asking a user to do it themselves. Address reuse might not make your money disappear on the spot, but it does significantly reduce your transnational privacy.